# Show :after when hovering over the parent element via CSS

Tags: css, hover, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Is it possible to `display:block;` the `:after` pseudo-element when I hover over the parent element itself?

```
#myDiv{
   position:relative;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border-style:solid;
   background-color:red;
}
#myDiv:after{
   position:absolute;
   content:"";
   display:none;
   width:50px;
   height:50px;
   border-style:solid;
   background-color:blue;
}
```

I have tired:

```
#myDiv:hover #myDiv:after{
    display:block;
}
#myDiv:hover + #myDiv:after{
    display:block;
}
#myDiv:hover > #myDiv:after{
    display:block;
}
```

Yet no luck, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8jmM/).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Change it to `#myDiv:hover::after`

You can use either `:after` or `::after` but in the selectors module (3) it states that the latter is now intended to be used to distinguish them from pseudo-classes

Comment: The spec says it is fine for backwards-compatibility to use `:` instead of `::`. It states new pseudo-elements should only work with `::`, but old ones are supported with both.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to reference the same element, so you don't need to duplicate the ID selector. No need to use the child selector either, just use:

```css
#myDiv:hover:after {
    display: block;
}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f8jmM/1/)