# How to change pseudo-element child when parent is hovered over?

Tags: hover, parent-child, pseudo-element

I'm trying to get an item that is a pseudo element to change when the parent is hovered over. The pseudo element here is .child:after. I know this works:

```
.parent:hover .child { 
   background: #FF0000; 
  }
```

But this does not seem to work:

```
.parent:hover .child:after { 
   background: #FF0000; 
  }
```

Any ideas? Thank you!!

Comment: Look at this post, maybe it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488827/show-after-when-hovering-over-the-parent-element-via-css

Comment: Thanks, that helped me figure it out, but the triangle still became a square when I hovered over it.

Comment: Similar situation of mine didn't work, because I had `#grandparent .parent .child: after` set before it, therefore setting `.parent:hover .child:after` didn't have enough strength and should have been `#grandparent .parent:hover .child:after`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `content:''` to `::after` pseudo-class;

Also be aware that `:after` works with non-replaced elements (im, input, textarea, and so on) (refference: [replaced elements](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements).)

Additionally: pay attention to display property of `.child:after` selector.

Here you go with a working example https://jsfiddle.net/wq2edhf3/.

Comment: Hi Ignat, it looks like I misjudged the situation. I have updated a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Clare12345/4s17m6vj/. I need the parent div's pseudo-element to change when the parent div is hovered over. The location of the :after in my developer tools in Chrome made me think it was the child's div. Could you let me know how to make the parent's pseudo-element hover work?

Comment: Try `.arrow_box2:hover::after` for your hover state ;). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/4s17m6vj/4/

Comment: For some reason this happens: https://jsfiddle.net/Clare12345/4s17m6vj/3/. The tooptip becomes a square box instead of the triangle.

Comment: Pay attention to a commented out border-color property https://jsfiddle.net/4s17m6vj/6/ 

it makes all of the borders became yellow, while combination of borders is a square ;)

Comment: That makes complete sense! I see now that the reason the triangle was a triangle is because only one border was showing up. Thank you!!!